# Run SQL Query in Phonegap

Tags: sql, database, phonegap

Hello everyone i am trying to run a query as follows, but i always get "SQL ERROR: undefined"

What am i doing wrong.

```js
db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "SQLDB", 200000);
RunQuery ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ARTIGOS");

function RunQuery(QueryExecute) {
    db.transaction(function(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql(QueryExecute,successCB,errorCB);
    })
}

function errorCB(err) {
 alert("SQL Error: "+err.message);
}

function successCB() {
 alert("SQL OK");
}
```

Comment: I think it is sqlite for phonegap/cordova to work with android phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the `transaction.executeSql` method takes a parameters array as its second argument. So to use the callbacks like you have, you may have to pass in an empty array for the parameters. e.g.:

```
transaction.executeSql(QueryExecute, [], successCB, errorCB);
```

Referenced from the Cordova docs here:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html